# I need to write a query in MySQL with multiple case and a single join that makes me error

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR(lead_date_time)='2020-03-04' AND JOIN t_settings ts ON ld.`lead_type`=ts.`setting_id` END) AS callsmade
       COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR(lead_date_time)='2020-02-04' THEN ld.soft_delete ='n' END) AS leads,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN lead_followup_date!='0000-00-00' AND YEAR(lead_date_time)='2020-03-04' 
    AND DATE(lead_followup_date) ='2020-02-04' THEN ld.soft_delete ='n' END) AS todaysappointments ,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN lead_followup_date !='0000-00-00' AND YEAR(lead_date_time)='".$seleted_year."' 
    AND DATE(lead_followup_date) >'2020-02-04' THEN ld.soft_delete ='n' END) AS upcomingappointments,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN lead_status ='Billed' AND YEAR(lead_date_time)='2020-03-04' THEN ld.soft_delete ='n' END) AS billedleads,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN lead_status ='qualified' AND YEAR(lead_date_time)='2020-03-04' THEN ld.soft_delete ='n' END) AS qualifiedleads,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN lead_followup_date !='0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND ((lead_assigned_to = '1') OR (ld.createdby ='1'))
    AND DATE(lead_followup_date) >='2020-03-01' THEN ld.soft_delete ='n' END) AS appointments,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN lead_followup_date !='0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND ((lead_assigned_to = '1') OR (ld.createdby ='1'))
    AND DATE(lead_followup_date) >='2020-03-01' THEN ld.soft_delete ='n' END) AS followup,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN lead_status ='Billed' AND ((lead_assigned_to = '1') OR (ld.createdby ='1'))
    THEN ld.soft_delete ='n' END) AS prospects

 FROM t_lead_details ld 

 WHERE ts.soft_delete='n'
```

Comment: you need to make expected results on fiddle

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: And what error do you wish to make?

Comment: i had error in that query could you solve that ?????

Comment: 'YEAR(lead_date_time)='2020-03-04' doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: I just need to add join inside case function

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are looking for a correlated sub query for example

```
SELECT (SELECT
            SUM(CASE WHEN date(lead_date_time)='2020-03-04' THEN 1 END) FROM t_settings ts WHERE ld.`lead_type`=ts.`setting_id` 
            ) AS callsmade
....
```

If this doesn't suit please add sample data and expected output to the questions as text.